# How do you conjugate the first-person imperative?

Tags: conjugación, imperativo

In English, you can command yourself for encouragement. For example, when you're lifting weights in the gym, you can yell at yourself, "**[Focus!](http://instagram.com/p/a-oAXRIh-Q/)** Come on! Do it!". However, in Spanish, the first-person imperative is always left blank in [conjugation tables](http://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/enfocar):

```
-        enfoquemos
enfoca   enfocad
enfoque  enfoquen
```

So how do you encourage yourself in sporting competitions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no first person singular imperative, that's why it doesn't appear in conjugation tables. I would even bet there isn't one in English.

So how do you encourage yourself? By talking to yourself in the second person:

```
¡Céntrate! ¡Hazlo! ¡Corre!
```

Answer (score 3):

You just use the second-person imperative, since you actually are speaking to someone (and that someone happens to be you).

Your example sentence would then be translated to

> ¡Céntrate! ¡Venga! ¡Hazlo!